# Read lines of a file, sort and return middle element

Tags: sorting, haskell, io, readfile, yesod

I am kind of new to IO with Haskell and although I read through it a lot, my code still won't work.

What I want the app to do:

1. Read all lines of a file (file1.txt, file2.txt, ...), where all contain numbers each line (floats like 1.12345)
2. Sort all these lines (string sorting or float sorting doesn't matter, I assume string sorting is faster?)
3. Get the middle element of the list and print it out

This is the code I do have so far. I can assure that the function "middle" works fine when passing a [String].

```
middle :: [a] -> a
middle xs = (drop ((l - 1) `div ` 2) xs) !! 0
            where l = length xs

getSortedMiddleElement :: Int -> String
getSortedMiddleElement i = do
    dat <- readFile $ "file" ++ (show i) ++ ".txt"
    return $ middle $ sort $ lines dat
```

I am calling getSortedMiddleElement from a "Int -> Content" function (I use Yesod), where the number is being passed via URL and the middle element should be returned to the user. To get Content out of a string, it needs to be "String", not "IO String"... How can this be easily achieved?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One possibility is to change the type to `Int -> IO String` and then treat the function like you would treat e.g. `readFile` or any other IO function.

Comment: Thank you, this sounds good so far! How do I handle `getTestR :: Int -> Handler RepPlain`, which returns the HTTP response? `getTestR :: Int -> IO Handler RepPlain` does not work :(

Comment: I wish I could tell you, but I'm in no way an expert on Yesod. :(

Comment: Maybe the `Handler` monad contains the `IO` monad already? You could try `liftIO (getTestR 5)`.

Comment: A `lift` will suffice, `Handler RepPlain` is a synonym for the transformer stack `HandlerT s IO RepPlain` (where `s` is the type of the foundation type, often named `App`. This is for Yesod 1.2, however, but since I don't know yuor version, that's the best answer I can give.

Comment: Where is the sorting, by the way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your type signature says that your function is pure (i.e., it takes an Int and returns a String) but inside, you are performing IO! Haskell will not let you write such a function. Anything you read from a file is forever stuck in the IO monad, and that's that (barring unsafe functions, of course).

In this case, that turns out to not be so bad, because Yesod is a heavily IO-based framework. All network traffic is stuck in the IO monad as well!

When you're in a monad transformer stack, you have access to monadic computations at each level of the stack, but only one of them *directly*. You use `lift` to move a computation from a monad one layer down in the stack into the transformed monad. If `IO` is in the stack, no matter how many layers down, you can access its actions directly via `liftIO`.

So if you have `type T = ReaderT String IO` then you may have a function `foo :: Int -> T String`. In this function, you'll be operating in the `T` monad, which transforms the `IO` monad with the `Reader` monad capabilities. In this context, you can say `lift readFile` and instead of getting an `IO String` result, you'll get a `T String` result! That's just an `IO String` wrapped in the `ReaderT` type, though, so don't think we did anything tricky like escaping the `IO` monad.  That might have been a bit confusing, so let's look at an example:

```
import Control.Monad.Reader (ReaderT)
import Control.Monad.Writer (WriterT)
import Control.Monad.Trans  (lift, liftIO)

type T = ReaderT String IO
getSortedMiddleElement :: Int -> IO String

foo :: Int -> T String
foo n = do
  str <- lift $ getSortedMiddleElement n --str holds a pure String now
  lift $ putStrLn str                    --get `putStrLn` from IO and pass the String
  return str                             --let's wrap it back in T now
```

But what if we're more than one layer away from IO? Let's try it out:

```
type W = WriterT String T -- WriterT String (ReaderT String IO)

-- This doesn't work; lift only gives you access to the next layer's actions
-- but IO is now more than one layer away!
--
--bar n = do
--  str <- lift $ getSortedMiddleElement n

-- Instead, we need liftIO, which will access IO across many transformer layers
bar :: Int -> W String
bar n = do
  str <- liftIO $ getSortedMiddleElement n
  liftIO $ putStrLn str
  return str
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer! `LiftIO` was exactly what I needed.